# Jquery Validation plugin and nyromodal Plugin

Tags: jquery, validation, nyromodal

Does anyone know the best way to get the Jquery Validation plugin to run when submitting a form that has been loaded dynamically into a Jquery nyromodal modal window?

Answer (score 0):

you should add the call to the validator function inside the callback from the form loading function, that is the validator plugin should be called after the form has been loaded.

A quick look at the nyromodal plugin shows a afterHideLoad callback, not sure this is the correct callback though.